# app:dexDebug error on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am running Android Studio 1.4 on Mac OS X. Everything was running ok until i updated some SDKs from the manager and then when i try to compile my app i get the error below.

My gradle settings are

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
```

**Error:**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Users/Haroon/Desktop/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /Users/Haroon/Desktop/ShopFront-Android/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/Users/Haroon/Desktop/ShopFront-Android/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

**UPDATE**

I am trying to implement `TabLayout` in my app and if i exclude the support design library then the app compiles:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you hit the dex method count limit (65,536 count).

You can fix it with add this in your defaultConfig

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

and this to your dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

and finally install it in your Application class

```
   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
       super.attachBaseContext(base);
       MultiDex.install(this);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Whats your logcat Throws

> com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
>   0xffff]: 65536
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)

The Android plugin for **`Gradle available in Android SDK Build Tools 21.1`** and higher supports multidex as part of your build configuration. Make sure you update the ***Android SDK Build Tools tools and the Android Support Repository to the latest version using the SDK Manager*** before attempting to configure your app for **multidex**.

Setting up your app development project to use a multidex configuration requires that you make a few modifications to your app development project. In particular you need to perform the following steps:

1. **Change your Gradle build configuration to enable multidex**
2. **Modify your manifest to reference the MultiDexApplication class**

*Modify your app Gradle build file configuration to include the support library and enable multidex output .*

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Read Official Document about
[MultiDex](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html)

If your Application class is extending some other class and you don’t want to or can’t change it, **`override attachBaseContext()`** as shown below:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { 
   @Override 
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) { 
      super.attachBaseContext(base); 
      MultiDex.install(this); 
   } 
}
```

### Conclusion

> While the library fixes the DEX 64K problem in most cases, it should
>   be treated as a last resort. Before attempting to use it, you should
>   audit your project for unwanted dependencies and remove as much unused
>   code as possible using ProGuard.

Comment: Try this way.I hope it will helps you

Answer (score 0):

You have crossed the method limit of 65536.
You need to enable Multidex in you application.

Add     `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` to your dependencies.

Also you need to set multidex enabled to true in your **build.gradle**.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

If you have an Application class then extent id with MultiDexApplication instead of Application.
If not then add it to your application tag in manifest like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

For a detailed answer please see [This](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).